# To change the date format

Tags: php

Sir,

```
$datfrs=$_REQUEST["datfrs"];
```

This is my php code here the `$datfrs` is the date and its format is (01 / Nov / 2013 ),I need to convert it into (2013-11-01) to fetch the value from data base.I looked through date function but the date format is changing to (1970-01-01) but I need it as(2013-11-01) .Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", " ",$_REQUEST["datfrs"])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps...

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $datefrs);
$formatted = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

The first argument to `DateTime::createFromFormat` should match the incoming format. I can't quite tell if the parentheses and spaces are included. Taken literally, the format would be something like

```
'(d / M / Y)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datfrs))

Answer (score -1):

Use this function to get your required date. This will surely work.

```
$datfrs=$_REQUEST["datfrs"];
$newdate=MyDateFormat($datfrs);
function MyDateFormat($date) // format is (01 / Nov / 2013 )
{
$exp=explode("/",$date);
$mon=date("m",strtotime($exp[1]))
$ndate=$exp[2]."-".$mon."-".$exp[0];
return $ndate;
}
```